# Doubt regarding the variable by which time complexity is measured

Tags: graph-theory, asymptotics, computational-complexity, computability

In order to assert that a given algorithm for graphs runs in polynomial time, must the variable in the big-O function that represents the run time (denoted henceforth as $O(f(n))$) be the number of vertices? Or can one say that a graph algorithm runs in polynomial time if the variable $n$ is something else (like the number of edges in a graph).

Edit: Could an algorithm that is $O(N)$ (where $N$ is the number of trees in the graph) also be considered as being in $P$?

Comment: The variable could be either of them or a subset of them. It will depend on the case for which time complexity is being determined.

Comment: $Nodes\leq 2Edges$ and $Edges\leq Nodes^2$ so a polynomial result for one implies a polynomial result for the other. (Assuming all nodes touch at least one edge)

Comment: If an algorithm is $O(N)$ (Where $N$) is the number of trees in a graph. then is that algorithm still in the complexity class $P$?

Answer (score 1):

**Informally:** An algorithm is polynomial time if the algorithm runs in time polynomial in the *size of the input*. Suppose the input for an algorithm is a graph $G$. Then letting $n$ be the number of vertices and $m$ the number of edges, if the algorithm runs in time polynomial in either $n$ or $m$, then that algorithm is considered a polynomial-time algorithm, since the size of $G$ is $n+m$.

An algorithm that runs in time say linear in the *number of trees $G$ has* [which may be exponential in the size of $G$] is not in $P$. Why? The graph $G$ itself encodes all the information needed for the algorithm and so could be the input. So the algorithm would not run in time polynomial in the size of $G$.

Comment: @HenningMakholm sure. But the OP asked about graphs explicitly, and generalizing,  it is whether an algorithm runs in time polynomial in the size of the input.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right, actually. Never mind.